# Edge Loop creates duplicate in 2.8

Tags: loop

Using the excellent tutorial by Andrew Price for intro to blender, I reached the point where he is making bendy sprinkles.  Using the edge loop just as he did doesn't bend the sprinkle; it creates some form of extrusion or duplicate, as shown in the screenshot.

What am I doing wrong, here?

Thanks in advance for any help on this question.  =)

BB[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPAAj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, for some reason, the vertices at the bottom of the top cap and the top of the bottom cap have been duplicated -- so there's a "hidden" set of faces in the middle, which you're exposing when you bend the other set out of the way.

If I'm right, fixing it will be easy. There are two options:

- If you can still undo the "extrusion": in Edit Mode, select all of the vertices with A. Then hit Alt-M, and click "By Distance". This will automatically merge all vertices that are within a certain very small threshold from one another, removing duplicates. After you've done that, you should find that the loop cut step works as expected.
- If you've already committed to the "extrusion": Select the extra faces (the ones that weren't affected by your loop cut) and delete them with X. Then do the same as I described above to merge the extra vertices.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I tried using the merge by distance; it had no effect. I'll attempt your second suggestion.  =)

Comment: That did the trick; the ghost is gone.  Any clue why that happened int he first place?

Comment: One thing that can cause it is cancelling an extrusion -- if you have a face selected, hit E to extrude, and then right-click, you've cancelled the *motion*, but not the extrusion itself. So the extruded face is still there, it's just exactly on top of the face you had selected, duplicating all of the vertices.

Comment: I'll remember that, though in this case the problem was with a freshly made duplicate having only the one edge loop applied to it.